# Preventing extra line-skipping before and after an equation environment

Tags: spacing, equations, environments

I am looking for something *I can insert into my preamble* which will yield the output of

```
lorem ipsum
\begin{equation}
math
\end{equation}
lorem ipsum
```

when I type it with double carriage returns before and after the environment, e.g.

```
lorem ipsum

\begin{equation}
math
\end{equation}

lorem ipsum
```

In particular, I need to have double-carriage returns before and after the environment (to make it easier to view), but I don't want the double-carriage return to effect the output when they surround the `equation` environment. Defining a new environment would be fine, as long as it behaves the same as `equation` and follows the same numbering scheme with `align`, `multline`, etc. environments.

I use double-carriage returns elsewhere in my file, so ideally this solution should be unique to the equation environment.

**EDIT:** double-lineskips are used elsewhere in the file to induce a single lineskip during typesetting. So essentially, I want a double-lineskip to "do nothing" when it surrounds the `equation` environment.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by, or intend to accomplish with, a "double carriage return". Double, triple, quadruple etc "carriage returns" usually all have the exact same effect -- *viz*., to create a paragraph break -- in TeX and LaTeX documents.

Comment: \abovedisplayskip=0pt \belowdisplayskip=0pt \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt (may be overkill).  Note, double spacing is for typewriters, not typesetting.

Comment: @Mico thanks, I edited my question. Multiple line skips are essentially used for two different purposes within my file. I'm looking for it to have a special meaning when they surround an equation environment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks, but unfortunately those preamble commands did not fix the issue. The output of the two lines above are still different

Comment: @Mico My apologies for the typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Some comments and observations:

- All-blank lines in TeX and LaTeX documents create paragraph breaks.
- The following statement is presumably blindingly obvious: One should only create paragraph breaks if, well, one *intends* to create paragraph breaks.
- As an iron rule, though, one should *never* create a paragraph break right before a displayed-math environment, be it an `equation`, `align`, `gather`, `multline`, or what have you environment.

Thus,

```
lorem ipsum

\begin{equation}
math
\end{equation}

lorem ipsum
```

is just wrong from a typographic point of view. If you simply *must* create a visual offset to satisfy your typing habits, you could go with either

```
lorem ipsum
%
\begin{equation}
math
\end{equation}

lorem ipsum
```

or

```
lorem ipsum
%
\begin{equation}
math
\end{equation}
%
lorem ipsum
```

depending on whether or not you wish to create a paragraph break *immediately after* the `equation` environment. By placing the comment character at the very start of the line, TeX never "sees" that line -- and hence doesn't get a chance to create a paragraph break.

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative answer, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Zim - You're most welcome!

Comment: Occasionally I'll put an extra blank line between a paragraph and displayed math that follows to solve issues with widow lines. Putting the blank line in the source pulls the widow back to the previous page and allows the displayed math to sit on the following page.

Comment: @RichardSullivan - I'm not sure if the analogy with wishing to avoid widow lines is fully appropriate here. The line (or lines) of text that precede the equation and the subsequent equation (whether single-line or multi-line) should be viewed as forming one *logical* paragraph. Hence, if just one line of a *text* paragraph is placed at the top of a page, followed immediately by an associated displayed equation, there are two or more lines of a *logial* paragraph at the top of that page's text block. I wouldn't call this a case of a widow line.